# Checking to see if their zip code is eligible

Tags: drupal

Hello I am working on a web page in drupal. One of the content is about a scholarship and there are certain zipcodes that are eligible for that scholarship. I was wondering if there is to have a search box within that web page were the user types in there zip code and than tells you if they are eligible or not I was thinking some javascript, but I was wondering if there is any better ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could use javascript on the client side or php (as Drupal is in php) on the server side.  The tradeoff with the javascript approach is you'll have to send all the valid zip codes (or some rule that computes them) to the client every time your page is loaded.  But the upside is then it'll be very fast for the client to try various zip codes (since no server communication will be needed).  And this may be easier for you to code.

For your use, you'd probably get better overall performance doing this in php on the server.  But then you'll need to be familiar with some form of client-server communication (ajax for instance) so that you can send the zip code back to the server and listen for a response.

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you do zip code validation in the browser, you should still validate the zip code server side again since there's nothing ensuring a malicious user doesn't circumvent the client side validation.